# knitr: Knitting separate Rnw documents within an Rmd document

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, r-markdown

I have a master R markdown document (Rmd) within which I would like to `knit` several **separate** Rnw documents (NO child documents) in one of the chunks. However, when I call `knit` on the Rnw document, the contained R code chunks do not seem to be processed, resulting in an error when trying to run `texi2pdf` on them.

Illustration of the situation:

Inside master.**Rmd**:

````
```{r my_chunk, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}

... some code ...

knit("sub.**Rnw**", output = ..., quiet = TRUE)

tools::texi2pdf(tex_file)

... some code ...


```
````

Is there some additional configuration required to make this scenario work?

Comment: +1 if at the very least as a hat tip for XLConnect.

Comment: Not good solution but you can do it by invoking new process from .Rmd: `system("R -e \"knitr::knit('sub.Rnw')\"")`

Comment: A MWE would be helpful here. Do you want the final document to include the output from knit("sub.Rnw", ...), or are you just generating separate pdfs from a single master Rnw file?

Comment: The idea is to generate separate PDFs from a single master Rmd page

Comment: If you provide short, complete Rmd and sub.Rnw documents it makes it much easier for someone else to debug your issue. With a single incomplete example file, you leave it for us to guess what you've done.

Comment: seems weird to want to output several documents from a .Rmd. Why don't you output your documents from a master script, that will knit all your documents ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few reasons you can't directly do what you are trying to do (calling `knit` from within a `knit` environment)...

1. Knitr patterns are already set.
   [ In this case markdown patterns, so you'd need to set the patterns to 'rnw' patterns. ]
2. Parsing the chunks (after setting the correct patterns) will add chunk labels to the existing concordance, so unless all chunks are unique you will get a duplicate chunk label error.
   [ This is why knit_child exists. ]
3. The output target and other options are already set, so you either need a completely new knitr environment or to save, modify, restore all pertinent options.

That being said, it seems like completely expected behavior.

Something along the lines of

```
library(knitr)

files <- list.files( pattern = "*.Rnw", path = ".")
files

## [1] "test_extB.Rnw" "test_ext.Rnw"

for( f in files ) {
  system( paste0("R -e \"knitr::knit2pdf('", f, "')\"") )
}

list.files( pattern="*.pdf", path=".")

## [1] "test_extB.pdf" "test_ext.pdf"
```

or calling `Rscript` in a loop should do the trick (based on the info provided), which is essentially what @kohske was expressing in the comments.